# Careers includes a "heart smiley" in company address?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I've just received an email reminding me I haven't updated my profile, and this is what I noticed when I scrolled down to the bottom:

[image]

I was just wondering if it was deliberate or whether it's a bit of a bug as it doesn't look too professional.

Otherwise, is it just that the SE offices are so brilliant - that love for them has to be declared even at the bottom of emails...

Comment: That is indeed unprofessional and certainly should not happen <3

Comment: Looks like a bug. 10038 is definitely >3

Comment: Did you see [this page](http://stackexchange.com/about/team)? If so, did you try to hover over the pictures? Give it a try. Enjoy. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'd better be careful I don't get David Fullerton set on me ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

100% Deliberate. We love everyone we send e-mail to :)

<3

Comment: umm - I'd feel more loved if I received some SO goodies through the letterbox though ;)

Comment: @JonClements Well SO's love hasn't been well received by you so far.  Perhaps if you were more appreciative...

Comment: I don't know if I can speak for the future, but when I completed the Annual User Survey, I got a sticker and a thank-you! To me, stickers and thank-yous are pretty much the same as love. <3

Comment: @ChrisForrence I know - but not when you're in the UK :(